# CAPL: How do I get the timestamp of the message containing a signal name?

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I am sure this is much simpler than I'm making it out to be, but...

In CAPL, I'm trying to ouput the timestamp for signals that have a certain value:

```
on signal_update XXX
{ 
   if ($XXX == 42) {
      message * msg  = { DLC = 15 };
  
      getThisMessage(msg, 15);
  
      write("Time: %f", messageTimeNS(msg));
   }
}
```

So given a signal update, how do I get the containing message and its timestamp? (BTW, the 'DLC=15' is just the maximum value that the compiler let me include. I'm unsure of the correct value.)

Comment: Do you need the message itself, or is the timestamp enough?

Comment: Right now, just the timestamp. This is as much a "need" for the output, as it is for me to understand CAPL programming and what information is available to the different handlers.

Another approach I though might work would be to catch the message containing the signel (the timestap exists there!) and unpack the message to get the signals, but I haven't seen how to do that yet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the current simulation time by using

```
timeNowNS();
```

while you are in a `on signal_update ...` block, the time returned is the time which caused the event handler to be executed; in this case when a message was received which contained the signal of interest.

The simulation time will not change during execution of the event handlers.

Comment: Yep. That's what I was looking for. Thanks!